# React redux inputs

Tags: reactjs, input, redux

This is a react form

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        number:state.number,
        id: state.id
    }
   
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        submitInput: (event) => {
        dispatch(handleChanger(event))
      }
    }
  };
class  Id extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super ();

        this.state = {
            NUMBER:'',
            ID:''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(events) {
        this.setState({
            [events.target.name]:events.target.value
        });
      }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="bodywrapper">
                <div className="projectcontainer">
                    <div className="textcontainer">
                        <div className="textheader">Files required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bodycontainer">
                        <div className="fileinput"> 
                            <input className="idforminput" 
                                placeholder="Project name" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                value = {this.state.ID}
                                name = "ID"
                                /></div>    
                        <div className="idtextcontainer">
                            <div className="filetext fileinput">Number of slides required</div>
                        <div className="fileinput"> 
                            <input className="idformnumberinput" 
                                   placeholder="10" 
                                   type="number" 
                                   onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                   onChange = {this.props.submitInput(this.state.ID)}
                                   name = "NUMBER" 
                                   value={this.state.NUMBER}/> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>      
                        {this.props.ID}    
                    </div>
                    <div className="buttoncontainer">
                        <button className="bottontext" 
                        
                                onClick ={this.props.submitInput(this.state.ID) }>
                                <a href="link.html">Next step</a> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        )
    }

    
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Id)
```

the handlechage add the value of inputs to the state.

and i need the state in globally,so used redux. MDTP use handleChanger action to add the values to reducer:

```
export const handleChanger = (event) => ({
        type:event.target.name,
        event:event
    })
```

So the type became ID it will add the corresponding value to the state of reducer:

```
export const handleChanger = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case NUMBER:
            return{
                ...state,
                number: action.event
            }
        case ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                id: action.event
            }
        default: return state
    }
}
```

so why this code is not working?
or could you suggest any other ways to add inputs to redux state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to maintain the state in your component as you want in the redux store.
Please check the following code

```
// reducer 
const initialState = { 
    ID: 0,
    Number: ''
}
const inputDataReducer = (state=initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_INPUT_DATA': {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}


// action 
export function setInputDataToRedux(name,value) {
    return {
        type:'SET_INPUT_DATA',
        payload: {
            [name]:value
        }

    }
}


class Id extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(events) {
        this.props.setInputDataToRedux(events.target.name,events.target.value);
      }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="bodywrapper">
                <div className="projectcontainer">
                    <div className="textcontainer">
                        <div className="textheader">Files required</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bodycontainer">
                        <div className="fileinput"> 
                            <input className="idforminput" 
                                placeholder="Project name" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                value = {this.props.ID}
                                name = "ID"
                                /></div>    
                        <div className="idtextcontainer">
                            <div className="filetext fileinput">Number of slides required</div>
                        <div className="fileinput"> 
                                <input className="idformnumberinput" 
                                   placeholder="10" 
                                   type="number" 
                                   onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                   onChange = {this.props.submitInput(this.state.ID)}
                                   name = "NUMBER" 
                                   value={this.props.NUMBER} 
                                /> 
                            </div>     
                        </div>      
                        {this.props.ID}    
                    </div>
                    <div className="buttoncontainer">
                        <button className="bottontext" 
                        
                                onClick ={this.props.submitInput(this.state.ID) }>
                                <a href="link.html">Next step</a> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        )
    }

    
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // fetch both id and number from reducer
    ID: state.reducer.ID, // add your reducer
    Number: state.reducer.number // add your reducer
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Id)
```

Comment: why there is no mapDispatchToProps ?

Comment: you can use the same mapDispatchToProps that you have created but make sure to add setInputDataToRedux

Comment: we set the  export function setInputDataToRedux(name,value) , where name is the attribute of input name="ID" and value as value ={this.props.ID} , So we can omit  the const initialState = { 
    ID: 0,
    Number: ''
} 

is that right?

Comment: The initialState is in the reducer. So if you omit the initialState, it will pass id and name from the store as undefined and the input would throw an uncontrolled component warning. Or you can use defaultProps to pass initialValue of id and number using prop-types npm package , if you are using one....
the component needs to have an initial value just like the one you were maintaining in your component state.